# Integrating elements of a matrix obtained by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration

the matrix U[t] is obtained by

`U[w1_,w2_,w3_,t_]:=NDSolveValue[u'[x]==-I*H[w1,w2,w3,x]*u[x],u[0]==IdentityMatrix[3],u,{x,0,Pi}][t]`

where H[w1,w2,w3,x] may be

`H[w1_,w2_,w3_,t_]:={{0,Cos[w1*t],Cos[w3*t]},{Cos[w1*t],0,Cos[w2*t]},{Cos[w3*t],Cos[w2*t],0}}`

I wanna Integral the elements of U[t], but

`NIntegrate[U[1,2,1,t][[1,1]],{t,0,Pi}]`

doesn't work

looking for an effective way to do this integral

Comment: what is `H`? what is `tau` ?

Comment: H is a 3x3 time-dependent matrix, tau is any ending time.

Comment: if H is 3 by 3 matrix, then what does `H[para]` actually mean?

Comment: It's a little unclear to me; is `H` dependent on `x` in `u'[x]==-I*H[para]*u[x]`?

Comment: I find everything confusing in this question. First `H` was a 3 by 3 matrix. Now it is a function that takes 4 arguments. `w1_,w2_,w3_,t_` then there is a call `H[para]` there. I am getting a headache now. I think I need to make more coffee :)

Comment: Sorry for saying not clear. question modified again.

Comment: You can not call `U[w1,w2,w3,t][[1,1]]` with symbolic arguments w1,w2,w3.

Comment: yep. numbers of wi are used when I want to do the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
H[w1_, w2_, w3_, t_] := {
    {0, Cos[w1 t], Cos[w3 t]},
    {Cos[w1 t], 0, Cos[w2 t]},
    {Cos[w3 t], Cos[w2 t], 0}
}

U[w1_, w2_, w3_]:= NDSolveValue[
    {u'[t] == - I H[w1, w2, w3, t] . u[t], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[3]},
    u,
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}
]

Derivative[-1][U[1, 2, 1]][Pi]
```

> {{1.59441 + 0.694679 I, -0.539096 - 1.45941 I, -0.539096 -
> 1.45941 I}, {0.489823 - 1.33736 I,
> 2.29704 - 0.354696 I, -0.651253 - 0.354691 I}, {0.489823 -
> 1.33736 I, -0.651253 - 0.354691 I, 2.29704 - 0.354696 I}}

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! What if I want to do a double integral after manipulating U[w1,w2,w3,t], like Integrate[Cos[t1-t2]*Tr[U[w1,w2,w3,t1].PauliMatrix[2]]*Tr[U[w1,w2,w3,t2].PauliMatrix[3]],{t2,0,t1},{t1,0,Pi}]?

Comment: @wannaintegrate It is possible, but would require a different approach. I think it is worth asking as a new question.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for your answer!